# How to iterate over two unique ID variables to find max value WITHOUT repeating either unique ID

Tags: r, iteration, tidyverse, subset, matching

I have joined two dfs each with their own unique ID variables: *topic* and *index*. There are 54 unique *topic* IDs and 54 unique *index* IDs for a total of 2916 obs in the df. Each obs features a numeric score in a variable called *value*. I would like to subset to a df of 54 obs that features the topic-index pairings with the highest *value* while avoiding the repetition of any *topic* or *index*. For example, in the sample below, *index* 349 is repeated in the first two rows for *topic* 33 and *topic* 2. I'd like to keep *index* 349 assigned to *topic* 33, but then *topic* 2 would be assigned to the *index* with the next highest value which is *index* 347 (row 4 in the sample). How do I accomplish this in code for the entire dataframe?

**SAMPLE**

```
df <- structure(list(topic = c(33L, 2L, 33L, 2L, 33L, 13L, 33L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 42L, 13L, 33L), index = c(349, 349, 363, 347, 342, 369, 
321, 366, 321, 363, 344, 370, 366), value = c(0.210311631079167, 
0.204938177956459, 0.201678820628508, 0.160801031631647, 0.160747075179686, 
0.154814646522019, 0.154102617910918, 0.137730410377001, 0.126294470150952, 
0.123695668664189, 0.110965846294849, 0.0999091218902647, 0.099824248465453
)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**Desired output**

```
output <- structure(list(topic = c(33L, 2L, 13L, 42L), index = c(349, 347, 
369, 344), value = c(0.210311631079167, 0.160801031631647, 0.154814646522019, 
0.110965846294849)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This code is obviously insufficient (and my sample above doesn't have 54 topics):
`df2 <- df %>% group_by(topic, index) %>% arrange(-value) %>% filter(top_n(54))`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are after. What's the desired output for this sample input that we can use for testing.

Comment: Could you describe your desired output a bit more? The algorithm you describe is not clear to me. Reducing the number of rows in the sample data might help clarify the issue as well.

Comment: in addition to above comments, topic 2 is already assigned to index 347. Also, index 347 is not the index with the next highest value. The index with the next highest value appears to be 363

Comment: Concerning the update: Most topics appear many times, should they all be assigned the same index?

Comment: Tried to add a sample of desired output. Appreciate all of the comments and patience.

Comment: My desired output is a df of 54 obs with each topic assigned to the index that maximizes value without repeating any topic or index. I have edited the question slightly to try and clarify my objectives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

A friend helped out with a possible function for this:

```
find_pairs <- function(df){
  
  store_max <- NULL
  search_data <- df
  
  for(i in 1:length(unique(df$topic))) {
    
    max_ind <- which.max(search_data$value)
    new_best <- search_data[max_ind,]
    
    store_max <- rbind(store_max, new_best)
    
    search_data <- search_data %>% 
      filter(topic != new_best$topic & index != new_best$index)
    
  }
  
  store_max
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42) # for reproducible random start example 
(d1 <- data.frame(topic=1:54))
(d2 <- data.frame(index=1:54))

(example_start <- expand_grid(d1,d2) |> 
  mutate(value=runif(n=n(),min=4,max=6)) |> 
  select(topic,index,value))
nrow(example_start)


example_start %>%
  group_by(index) %>% 
  slice_max(value, n = 1) |> ungroup()
```